# DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged not firing

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using this [sample](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/10/31-days-of-mango-day-10-network-information/) to get started with Windows phone 7.1 sdk. 
I use a button under Wi-Fi status to enable/disable it. On button click I start the ConnectionSettingsTask to change the status. I change the status. After that if I come back to app screen I don't see status updated in my application. Moreover I did not see NetworkAvailabilityChanged event firing in debug mode.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Ram, the Network is always available in DEBUG mode when programming for WP7 (emulator and connected WP7 device), which is probably the reason NetworkAvailabilityChanged never fires.

I would try the application on a device again without debugging to get a better idea of whats going on.